# connect two devices via socket that are not on the same network?

Tags: android, python, sockets, network-programming

while working on a project involving a python socket server and an android client, I couldn't figure out how to connect my phone's and my computer's sockets without having them using the same network. It is essential to my project. Is it actually possible? and if so, how is it done?
the error I'm getting is ETIMEOUT in the connection, meaning the connection was not established at all. 
In the following example the least i need to see is the server program noticing that the android socket has tried to connect to it.

Basic Android Client just for the example:

```
    public class sybel extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.0.106";
    private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 7777;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public BufferedReader in ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sybel);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
        new NetBeacons().execute();
}
public class NetBeacons extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... params) {
        try {
            try {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIpAddress, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT), 0);
                Log.d("XXX",socket.isConnected()+"");
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                //here it sends the data
                outToServer.print("hi");
                outToServer.flush();
                Log.i("sybel",dis.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("XXX",result);

    }


    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

Basic Python server:

```
    import socket
    import select
    server_socket=socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7777))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    open_client_sockets = []
    while True:
        rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select([server_socket]+open_client_sockets,[],[])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is server_socket:
                (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            else:
                data = current_socket.recv(1024)

                if data=="":
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                    print "Connection with client closed"
                else:
                    print data
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You'll have to open port 7777 in your firewall, and direct traffic to your-external-ip:7777 to your-internal-ip:7777.

Comment: (And change the IP your client is using from your-internal-ip (192.168.0.106) to your external IP (try googling for what is my IP to find that out)

Comment: hi, I usually program in school, where there is no option to modify firewall configuration (the school blocks it) so it will not work.. is there any other option? thanks for your answer

and @Foon ,  consider that ip as my public one

Comment: Another option (which is offtopic here) would be to look at hosting your code on something with a free tier option (e.g. heroku, I think)... this way the server has a public-facing IP.